# Data not displaying in dropdown using select2 with ajax and Even i can not select any data

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, codeigniter, jquery-select2

Hi guys I am working with Select2 with ajax, issue is the data is not showing in the dropdown when I click on the option.
Other than that when I try to search any specific thing. Data is processed but doesn't showing in the dropdown. I have checked the data in `console.log()` it is showing properly before or after searching
for further details I will share my code have a look and let me know the issue.

**script:**

```
$(document).ready(function() {
      $('#user-list').select2({
        ajax: {
          url: "<?php echo base_url() . 'User_basic/fetch_mobile_numbers'; ?>",
          dataType: 'json',
          type: "post",
          delay: 250,
          data: function (params) {
           return {
             searchTerm: params.term // search term
           };
          },
          processResults: function (response) {
           console.log(response);
           return {
            results: response
          };
        },
       }
    });
 });
```

**View:**

```
<select name="phone_number" id="user-list" placeholder="Enter Number" class="form-control" multiple="multiple" required>
   <option value="" id="numbers-list"></option>
</select>
```

**JSON response sample**

```
[{"phone":"+924444444444"},
{"phone":"+926666666660"},
{"phone":"+92000000600"},
{"phone":"+923665588975"},
{"phone":"+929966557711"},
{"phone":"+92255663377"},
{"phone":"+921155775544"},
{"phone":"+925588665544"}]
```

Comment: please show us an example of the JSON response data

Comment: please include it in the question, not comments (use the "edit" button on the question). Thanks.

Comment: If your response format is conformed with selected2, you should try `response = JSON.parse(response);  return {results: response };`

Comment: @ADyson you can see it now in the post :)

Comment: @o0omycomputero0o i have posted the response as well please have a look

Comment: It seem you should convert data to has id and text: https://select2.org/data-sources/formats

Comment: Ok thanks. I agree, I think your data is not in the format select2 expects. I can't guess what fields you provided in the JSON or what you want to do with them, you have to return data in the right structure so it can you understand what you're giving it. If for any reason you can't alter what the server is returning you'll have to write some JavaScript code to modify it before you pass it to select2.

Comment: @o0omycomputero0o JSON.parse won't be necessary - specifiying `dataType: "json"` in the jQuery $.ajax options means that jQuery parses the data to an object automatically. But I fully agree with your second comment regarding the data format.

Comment: @o0omycomputero0o i think data is in correct format but further i have tried this conversion  as well its not working at all

Comment: @YasirMehmood No, the data is not in the correct format - select2 doesn't know what your "phone" field is. Read the link in mycomputer's comment above. The objects you pass to select2 should have the format `{
      "id": 1,
      "text": "Option 1"
    }`

Comment: `select2` expects both an `id` field and a `text` field. None of those are in your response. You could map `phone` to `text`, but `id` is still missing.

Comment: @ADyson i am stuck in this problem from last 5 hours and i have tried multiple different things mentioned in select2 documentation but its not working
and 1 thing more please can you share the format select2 accepts to have an idea:)

Comment: I already did. And it's in the link that mycomputer gave you 10 minutes ago. Please **read it**. If you've been stuck for so long, how did you not manage to find that piece of simple documentation already??

Comment: Sorry for asking again and again friends 
`[{"id": "3",
"phone":"+924444444444"
}]`
like this?

Comment: No. Read the page **properly**. Which part of (and I quote directly from the documentation) "Each object should contain, at minimum, an **id** and a **text** object" is proving hard to understand??

Comment: @ADyson okay dear let me read it once again carefully

Comment: I will write an answer so it's 100% clear.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The documentation at https://select2.org/data-sources/formats says:

> Select2 expects a very specific data format....Each object should contain, at a minimum, an **id** and a **text** property.

*(My bold.)*

Your JSON object contains neither of these properties. As such, select2 doesn't know what to do with the information you're giving it. It isn't expecting a "phone" property and won't look for it. It looks specifically for the fields mentioned in the documentation, and nothing else.

The data you give to select2 needs to look something like this:

```
[
  {"id": 1, "text":"+924444444444"},
  {"id": 2, "text":"+926666666660"},
  {"id": 3, "text":"+92000000600"},
  {"id": 4, "text":"+923665588975"},
  {"id": 5, "text":"+929966557711"},
  {"id": 6, "text":"+92255663377"},
  {"id": 7, "text":"+921155775544"},
  {"id": 8, "text":"+925588665544"}
]
```

You can probably whatever you wish into the "id" field, but it must be there, and the values must be unique.

Ideally you should change your server-side code to provide the JSON in this format directly. If for any reason that is not possible, then you'll have to write some code within the `processResults` JavaScript function to transform the data before you pass it to select2.

Comment: @ Yasir Mehmood: I've created codepen: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/oapeob ; text is required; id should be required - you can try to change and see no result if not set text.

Comment: @o0omycomputero0o thank you very much 
please let me know how to provide you a good rating

Comment: @Yasir Mehmood: Just upvote my comment (if you can) and accept ADyson for his detail answer :)

Comment: @o0omycomputero0o dear i have marked the answer as solution but 
i can not upvote comments it only shows red flag :( :( :(

Comment: @Yasir Mehmood: thanks, no problem :) maybe you upvote serveral times on my comment before.

Comment: @YasirMehmood See https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/vote-up - you need 15 reputation to upvote questions, comments and answers. Not far to go!

Comment: @o0omycomputero0o no, he just hasn't got enough rep yet

Comment: @ADyson: I've remembered, I was too long before ago... :)

Comment: No i have 17rep and i have upvoted your comment @o0omycomputero0o 
thanks alot for the help both of you :) :) :)

Comment: @YasirMehmood that's great. When I was writing the comment you seemed to have 12. Onwards and upwards...

Answer (score -1):

Try to made your select options in the controller side and send the html from the controller to the view file and then at the view side just make a simple div and give that html to that div.
Hope this will help you

Comment: did you even read the question? This advice is a) irrelevant to the issue of the data format and b) too vague anyway. You're suggesting to redesign the whole interaction between client and server, but the fix is much simpler, and you haven't explained why OP's code isn't working, either, and why they would need such a solution.